# How to create and subclass custom UIPickerView which shows only date, in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

In swift, how to create custom picker view by subclass UPickerView, so it shows only date picker? Couldn't find answer for this. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to create subclass for that,create UIDatePicker object set its property datePickerMode to UIDatePickerModeDate and it will show only date.ex. _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

Comment: There are different places I have to create same picker view with date, so I don't want to set the mode everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
class CustomPicker: UIDatePicker {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.datePickerMode = .Date

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Create instance like this:

```
let picker = CustomPicker(frame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 200, 200))
```

I have set the frame for demo purpose.

Comment: to override other properties, do i need to assign in init constructor ?

Comment: Yes. You can made your initial setup in the init constructor.

Answer (score 1):

to be able to instantiate the picker from code AND storyboard you have to override both initializers like this:

```
class DatePicker: UIDatePicker {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit() {
        datePickerMode = .Date
    }
}
```